# Same request sent twice has two different responses

Tags: ruby, rack

Please consider this test:

```rb
def test_ok_on_second_request
  bad_response = @request.get "/bad-response"
  assert_equal 404, bad_response.status

  good_response = @request.get "/test-title"
  assert_equal 200, good_response.status
  assert_equal "text/html", good_response.content_type
end
```

I have assured that `/test-title` is a valid path. The assertion that's supposed to return `200` is in fact returning `404`. *How is Rack behaving in order to return two different results for the same request?*

This is the code for the Server class inside the project:

```rb
module Blogrite
  class Server
    attr_accessor :status, :mimetype, :body, :provider
    def initialize *args, &block
      @status, @mimetype = 200, "text/html"
      provider = args[0][:with].nil? ? :filesystem : args[0][:with]
      @provider = Blogrite.const_get(provider.capitalize).new
      # p "Server is running with #{@provider.class}."
    end

    def call env
      begin
        article   = go env['PATH_INFO'].delete("/")
      rescue Blogrite::Article::NoBodyError
        @status = 404
      end

      @status   = 404 if !article
      @status   = 403 if env["REQUEST_METHOD"] == 'POST'
      @mimetype = "text/css" if env["PATH_INFO"].include?("css")
      @body     = if article then article.render
                  elsif env.respond_to?(:to_yaml) then "<pre>#{env.to_yaml}</pre>"
                  else "oops"
                  end

      [@status,{ "Content-Type" => @mimetype},[@body]]
    end

    def go path
      f = @provider.fetch path
      Article.parse f unless f.nil?
    end
  end
end
```

The whole workflow is too big for me to paste it in but you can check the project out on [Github](http://github.com/josemota/blogrite). I appreciate your help, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution for the problem is as simple as initializing `@status` inside the `call` function.

```rb
    class Server
      attr_accessor :status, :mimetype, :body, :provider
      def initialize *args, &block
 -      @status, @mimetype = 200, "text/html"
        provider = args[0][:with].nil? ? :filesystem : args[0][:with]
        @provider = Blogrite.const_get(provider.capitalize).new
        # p "Server is running with #{@provider.class}."
      end

      def call env
        begin
 -        article   = go env['PATH_INFO'].delete("/")
 +        @status, @mimetype = 200, "text/html"
 +        article = go env['PATH_INFO'].delete("/")
        rescue Blogrite::Article::NoBodyError
          @status = 404
        end
```

That way the rack instance – that is called only once – stays out of the request's way. Every call function should have its own defaults, not the server class.

Thanks to [@rubenfonseca](http://twitter.com/rubenfonseca) for helping me out.